# How to use `countif` in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I need help to for using `countif` in QuickSight.

eg: we have:

```
        name    id
        karthik 1
        harsha. 2
        karthik 3
        Vikram  4
        karthik 5
```

I want the syntax in QuickSight for counting the number of records `karthik` has in the above. Example answer is 3.

Please help with this.

Comment: [countIf - Amazon QuickSight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/countIf-function.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this syntax:

```
countIf(id, name='karthik')
```